# How to set default retention policy and duration for InfluxDB via configuration

Tags: configuration, influxdb

I am using the official InfluxDB docker image. I want to set the retention policy to be `14 days` by default.

There are various `ENV` variables that I can set to change the config for InfluxDB, such as `INFLUXDB_RETENTION_POLICY`. This expects the name of a retention policy such as "default" to be used as the default retention policy.

The problem is that this default policy has a duration of 7 days. I need to set it to 14 days.

The documentation is rather poor. I cannot find any `ENV` variable to adjust the default duration. I could also set the `INFLUXDB_RETENTION_POLICY` variable to a different name of a different retention policy, but I don't see how I can create that retention policy through configuration.

Is anyone aware of:
1) a way to change the default duration for retention via configuration
or
2) a way to create a retention policy through configuration

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to set the default retention policy via the configuration. The reason for this is that typically retention policy duration is defined during database creation.

```
CREATE DATABASE <database_name>
[WITH [DURATION <duration>] [REPLICATION <n>]
      [SHARD DURATION <duration>] [NAME <retention-policy-name>]]
```

If users were allowed to set a default retention duration via the configuration, the results of the command

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
```

would vary from instance to instance. While this isn't necessarily problematic, it isn't ideal either.

> The problem is that this default policy has a duration of 7 days. I need to set it to 14 days.

The default retention policy in InfluxDB should be infinite.

```
> CREATE DATABASE mydb
> SHOW RETENTION POLICIES ON mydb
name    duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----    -------- ------------------ -------- -------
autogen 0s       168h0m0s           1        true
```

Here we see that the duration of the retention policy is `0s` which is an alias for infinite and the shard group duration is `168h0m0s` which is 7 days.

I think the main point of confusion here is relatively common--and mostly due to retention policies being poorly named. In InfluxDB an Database is a container for Retention Policies and a Retention Policy is a container for the actual time series data. That is to say a Retention Policy isn't so much of a policy as it as a container that has a policy for all data it contains.

My recommendation would be to always be fully explicit when creating a database in InfluxDB. Doing so will always guarantee that your database will have the correct retention policy duration. So for creating a database with a 14 day retention policy you'd issue the command

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH DURATION 14d
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up for me. We are creating our one database in InfluxDB through configuration as well, and we only specify the name.

Seems silly to me, but we are running InfluxDB in a docker container in a kubernetes pod and it is not clear to me yet how to automate this bit of setup.

The docker volume for InfluxDB doesn't get created until kubernetes creates the pod so...another problem for another day.

Comment: Looking at [this documentation](https://github.com/influxdata/docs.influxdata.com/blob/master/content/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/database_management.md) it looks like you can change the default retentopn policy: CREATE RETENTION POLICY "one_day_only" ON "NOAA_water_database" DURATION 23h60m REPLICATION 1 DEFAULT

Comment: You can also change the existing autogen policy with `alter retention policy "autogen" on "mydb" duration 2w shard duration 1w replication 1 default`.

Comment: Thanks @hlovdal, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 19):

To answer the question for those coming from google with an existing database (this was my situation), there are three ways to set the retention policy:

- On a new database, with database create (as above)
- On create of retention policy, by adding DEFAULT at the end of the create statement
- By **altering** an existing retention policy to be the default for the db (see below)

**Creating a database**

> CREATE DATABASE "NOAA_water_database" WITH DURATION 3d REPLICATION 1 SHARD DURATION 1h NAME "liquid"

**Creating a policy**

> CREATE RETENTION POLICY "one_day_only" ON "NOAA_water_database" DURATION 1d REPLICATION 1

**Updating an existing policy**

> ALTER RETENTION POLICY "what_is_time" ON "NOAA_water_database" DURATION 3w SHARD DURATION 2h DEFAULT

So for an existing database and retention policy which you wish to make the default, the simplest solution is to use alter retention policy.

One point to note on adding/updating a policy on an existing db - data prior to the policy expiration will be immediately dropped, so you will lose all older data.

Comment: I know this wasn't in the OP question, but it would help if you'd just summarized what the difference between the two durations are, "duration" vs "shard duration" (because if you don't know how to set the retention policy on your influxdb you might not know or remember what a shard is either :)

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the mentioned environment variable to change influxdb retention policy doesn't work such as `DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_RETENTION`  mentioned in the [hub.docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb?tab=description). That's why this [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker/issues/282) is open since 2018 up to now.

Nevertheless, I use `.iql` file to set a retention policy that should be located in the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` inside the container with the following content:

`setretention.iql`:

```sh
CREATE RETENTION POLICY "two_hours" ON "metrics" DURATION 2h REPLICATION 1 SHARD DURATION 1h DEFAULT
```

Actually, I create a new retention policy named *two_years* on *metrics* database with `2h` duration and other stuff as mentioned. Therefore, its docker command would be as follows:

```sh
docker run --rm -d --name influxdb \
    -e INFLUXDB_REPORTING_DISABLED=true \
    -e INFLUXDB_DB=metrics \
    -e INFLUXDB_USER=retention_test \
    -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=testing123! \
    -v ./setretention.iql:/docker-entrypointinitdb.d/setretention.iql \
    influxdb:1.7.11
```

To check that:

```sh
$ docker exec -it influxdb influx
> show retention policies on metrics

name      duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----      -------- ------------------ -------- -------
autogen   0s       168h0m0s           1        false
two_hours 2h0m0s   1h0m0s             1        true
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- Bear in mind, follow [this table](https://archive.docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#what-is-the-relationship-between-shard-group-durations-and-retention-policies) for choosing the right values for related `retention policy duration` as well as `shard group duration`.

---

[UPDATE Apr 2022]

Apparently, due to this approved [pull request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker/pull/421), you can use the mentioned `.iql` query directly as an environment from *influxdb 1.9* onward.

Answer (score 1):

No one here really answered the question. The answer is that you can't create a retention policy with configuration files or env variables. So, in order to automate the solution you will need to create a "K8s Job" that import your commands into the influx CLI.

For example:

- First create this command file and wrapped it to "db_init.txt" file:

  CREATE DATABASE example CREATE RETENTION POLICY twoweeks ON example
  DURATION 14d REPLICATION 1 DEFAULT
- Second, create a bash script to upload this file directly to Influx
  CLI:

  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  influx -import -path=/tmp/db-init.txt

Wrap it up in a image and upload it as a job - and you got it automated.

Hope i have manage to help a little.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set a retention policy for all databases influxDB via config. Most probably because `retention policy` is a container that contains your actual compressed time-series data. And it's a property of each individual database. Changing the retention policy for one database will not change the retention policy for any other.

> If a retention policy is deleted then all the data it contains will be deleted. But altering the retention policy will not delete any data.

So here is a bash script to automate this task of altering retention policy

```
for db in $(influx -username $INFLUX_USERNAME -password $INFLUX_PASSWORD -execute="SHOW DATABASES"| grep <pattern_to_list_required_db>); do 
influx -username $INFLUX_USERNAME -password $INFLUX_PASSWORD -execute="ALTER RETENTION POLICY \"autogen\" ON \"$db\" DURATION 14d"
influx -username $INFLUX_USERNAME -password $INFLUX_PASSWORD -database="$db" -execute="SHOW RETENTION POLICIES"
done
```